# How to call an Output Parameter from a Mysql stored procedure in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, phpmyadmin

I am having a problem returning an output parameter from a Mysql stored procedure into a ASP.NET Variable.
I just want the ligne code to use in ASP to get that Parameter !
Thank you

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve] of your progress so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's suppose that there is a parameter named 'MyOutParam' which is an `output` type of parameter for your MySQL stored procedure. In that case what you will have to do is:

```
// here goes the logic of instantiating the command for a stored procedure

// cmd is the reference variable containing instance of SQLCommand
cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter(“MyOutParam”, MySqlDbType.VarChar));
cmd.Parameters[“MyOutParam”].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;         // this is how we declare the parameter to be of 'output' type.

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

// this is how we can get the value in the output parameter after stored proc has executed
var outParamValue = cmd.Parameters[“MyOutParam”].Value;
```

Comment: I suspect that code won't compile as is due to `”`.

Comment: Thank you sir , i'll try it :)

Comment: Oh great it's work :) 
thank you very much for your help and support!